# LLVM Clang and Makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu

I'm working on a migration task from a GNU to a LLVM compiler.

The first question is, how to deal with Makefile in an existing project.
What is the counterpart to make.exe of GNU?

Comment: Make is neither part of gcc nor of clang, it's a separate tool (or family of tools) that works equally well with both compiler (as with practically all other compilers). Make [46 years old now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)), BTW, 11 years older than GCC and perhaps 25 years older than clang.

Comment: You still use `make`, but you likely need to edit the `Makefile`. Often the `Makefile` contains an assignment for the `CC` variable specifying the compiler. It may be as easy as changing `CC = gcc` to `CC = clang`. But it might also be much more complicated.